# How can I get a list of answers (not questions) for a tag sorted by most votes?

Tags: support, tags, answers, upvotes

It is easy to get a list of questions sorted by most votes for a given tag.
For example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git?sort=votes&pageSize=50

Is there a way to get a list of the top answers for a tag? Replacing "questions" with "answers" doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a different sort of search; you would have to enter in the tag you want followed by `is:answer` in the search bar at the top right.

It would look like this:

```
[git] is:answer
```

[Here's a link to your exact query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bgit%5d%20is%3aanswer), sorting all Git answers by votes.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `is:a` instead of `is:answer`. Shorter, though same exact meaning and outcome.